# Why are some busybox commands in interactive mode not available in a chrooted environment?

Tags: command-line, chroot, busybox

I try to setup a most minimal chrooted environment using busybox.
I created a directory 'testRoot' and copied 'busybox' into it.

from this directory I execute:

```
sudo chroot ./ /busybox sh
```

now I have an interactive environment. commands like 'ls' and 'pwd' work:

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
/ # ls
busybox  testje
/ # pwd
/
/ #
```

some others (like 'vi') doesn't:

```
/ # vi
sh: vi: not found
```

on the otherhand starting vi outside the interactive shell works:

```
sudo chroot ./ /busybox vi
```

and outside the chrooted environment in the interactive shell there is also no problem:

```
eldendo@eldendo-WIM2140:~/testRoot$ busybox sh
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
~/testRoot $ vi (--- vi starts up here ---)
~/testRoot $
```

Any idea's ?

Comment: I don't think `vi` is within your  `chroot`. Check out it `which vi`

Comment: @kenn: no it isn't... I want to use the buildin vi in busybox (the help in busybox list 'vi' as a buildin command)

Comment: @kenn: but 'which vi' in the not chrooted example gives /usr/bin/vi ... So maybe vi is not buildin (although the 'help' pretends it is)...

Comment: I *suspect* it's because `CONFIG_BUSYBOX_EXEC_PATH` is set to `/proc/self/exe` and your chroot doesn't mount /proc - see for example [I selected "standalone shell" option and now I have problems](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#standalone_shell). However I don't know the right way to address it - nor why some commands (such as `ls`) work. You will likely find that `/busybox vi` inside the chroot does work.

Comment: @steeldriver: indeed it does...

Comment: ... and if I bind-mount /proc before entering the chroot plain `vi` works - although obviously that somewhat subverts the whole point of the chroot